# Strange object - vector or list?

Tags: r

```
a<-c(AA=4.7,BB=2,CC=7.5)
typeof(a) #double
```

What is the object "a"? Is this a numeric vector,string vector or a list?

Comment: named vector... Try `names(a)`, and `unname(a)`. Also try `setNames(1:5, letters[1:5])`

Comment: `> is.vector(a)
[1] TRUE`

Comment: Yes thanks it is indeed a vector, but why it is numeric vector?

Comment: Because it holds numeric and not character or boolean values.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik : This vector holds character values also.

Comment: Those are "just" names, and not values with which R functions do calculations with. Which is why it's called a named vector as mentioned by @Sotos.

Comment: ok thanks very much ;)

Comment: @wolf_wue Be very careful with the meaning of `vector` in R. What do you think `is.vector(list(a=1,b=2:10))` returns?

Comment: In R you can attach attributes to any object. The names you're assigning to each value, are stored in an attribute called "names" attached to the numeric vector. Have a look at the structure running : `str(a)`

Comment: @nicola thanks to your advice, but at all I'm quite familiar with R an its behaviour with vectors. Indeed the question considers whether `a` is a `vector` or a `list` ....

Comment: @wolf_wue the point I wanted to raise is that an object can be *both* a `vector` and a `list`...

Comment: @wolf_wue you need `is.vector(a) && is.atomic(a)` to test this correctly.

Comment: Actually from all answers in this thread and whole topic, the first answer of @Sotos entirely explained my doubts. Sotos it would be nice if you write it as a answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have a named vector which is still a numeric vector. You wouldn't expect a column of a data frame to be a character simply because its name is a string. Same happens here.

To become clear, just try

```
names(a)
unname(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You check the class, mode, type etc, with the following functions. In your case:

```
class(a)
[1] "numeric"

mode(a)
[1] "numeric"

typeof(a)
[1] "double"

is.atomic(a)
[1] TRUE

is.list(a)
[1] FALSE
```

From the official R Help pages:

> It is a historical anomaly that R has two names for its floating-point
>   vectors, double and numeric (and formerly had real).
>
> double is the name of the type. numeric is the name of the mode and
>   also of the implicit class.

For more, type `help("double")` in the console.

Comment: `is.vector` is quite useless here since a list is also a vector. If you need a vector in the stricter sense you should (also) test with `is.atomic`. But usually you need a specific class anyway if you validate input ...

Comment: Updated according to your feedback, @Roland.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused with `atomic vector`/`vector` and `lists`. I think @nicola correctly pointed out about vectors in the comment.In R when we say vectors, it actually means whether it is an atomic vector or a list. You can determine them by checking their 3 properties namely type, length and attributes.

Hence to check for an object whether it is a vector or not, you must check this : `is.atomic(x) || is.list(x)` . Off course In your case it is TRUE. which suggest it is a vector of atomic type.

Adding to above, the atomic vectors are further mainly segregated into integer, logical, double(numeric) and character .

Use `typeof()` when you want to determine the specific type such as integer, logical etc.

Now there are two other things that you can check which is `class` and `mode`.

`class()` is used to identify what "type" an object is from the point of view of object-oriented programming, you will find `class` at times superset of `type`. Such as in your case "a" is basically a "double" type object under the class numeric.

`mode()` gives the "type" of object from the point of view of authors.

Now to answer your question:

object "a" is of double type in the class numeric. You can check that by running typeof(a) and class(a) on your console.

There is another thing called `storage.mode` in r and from documentation of `?storage.mode` :

> Both mode and storage.mode return a character string giving the
>   (storage) mode of the object — often the same — both relying on the
>   output of typeof(x)

Please read "Advanced R" from Hadley Wickham and most of the stuff I learnt is from that book only. Link is [**here**](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html). You may also want to look for  [**R Language Definition**](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/manual/R-lang.html#Objects).

**NOTE**: I hope I am clear with what I want to convey. If anyone find any error in my understanding, please let me know. But to the best of my understanding I am almost certain that this is the way of looking objects in R.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this with:

```
class(a)
```

The code you used is for creating a vector then the code `class(a)` Should say that a is a vector.

Comment: ok, but why this vector is numeric?

Comment: @mokebe yes the vector is numeric, but you have assigned a name to the elements of vector